# Regex for name with non-latin characters in python

Tags: regex, validation

Looking for regex that validates a name.

**Valid name:**

- Barack Hussein Obama
- Barack-Obama
- Barack
- aa
- Aa
- Abc
- abc
- abcd
- ab
- Barack-Obama
- Barack
- aa
- Aa
- Abc
- abc
- abcd
- ab
- crazybcÜüßäÄöÖàâäèéêëîï nameôœùûüÿçÀÂ-ÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ
- sÜüßäÄöÖàâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜΘεσσαλονίκηŸМоскваÇ

**Not valid names are:**

- a-b
- a
- A
- b
- B
- Barack Obama.
- Simon.-#+;:_*´`?=)(/&%$§!123456789
- Simon.-#+;:_*´`?=)(/&%$§!123456789
- Donald B. Trump
- D. B. Trump

I am very close to a correct regex:

```
^[^\W\d_]+(?:[-\s][^\W\d_]+)*?$
```

I am using python!

Comment: Should there be 2 or more chars? `^[^\W\d_]{2,}(?:[-\s][^\W\d_]{2,})*?$` https://regex101.com/r/i6JaWX/1

Comment: Can you make an example please? Maybe there is sth, I didn't think of

Comment: @regex101: Yes, more then 2 chars! Your expression looks very good. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Thefourthbird, that's worthy a post. @PParker, do you mind using `regex` module and switching from a negated character class to matching any kind of letter from any language? If not then: `^\p{L}{2,}(?:[- ]\p{L}{2,})*?$`